# Debug error when trying to run on VS Code/Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I try and run debug I get an error saying something like "Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException"

How do I fix this issue so I can debug?

EDIT: **I am on a windows computer.**

Comment: Are you using an emulator or connected to a physical device?

Comment: emulator on windows pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is an issue with Android Q itself and I have downgraded to Android Pie and debugging now works, if you have issues try downgrading to Android Pie API level 28 if using Android Emulation.

Answer (score 0):

You may find [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25112) helpful where someone had a similar issue and managed to fix it by putting `NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1` in their `.bash_profile` and then restarting their terminal.

Comment: I am on a windows computer, is there any way to find that?